# How to modify the text of a navigation menu

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I am trying to modify the menu text of sections of a web made with this template:

The menu that I want to modify is the one that appears under the main picture.
This menu, is made with the titles of the different sections that make up the page. In the code of the template, the development of this menu is not shown, just put this:

```
<div class="listing-detail-menu-wrapper">
  <div class="listing-detail-menu">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills"></ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I imagine, from what I've seen, that this menu is generated by some js (I'm not sure)

Anyone has any idea how I can modify the text of this menu, and that this, is not necessarily the titles of the sections?

Comment: Can you show the rendered DOM structure of the menu that you want to style? Because the HTML you've shown gives no indication as to where the text, nor the image you refer to, is placed.

Answer (score 0):

Make your own class and then inside it make a unorder list for the menu and arrange the ul through CSS. I think the class name are of Bootstrap, so it will not work in simple html.

Comment: **<ul class="nav nav-pills"> _your_ _menu_ _list_ </ul>**

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, run the JQuery code to change the menu title when page load. I guess you have a fixed number of menus so you can change the `title` of each menu.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
   var allMenus = $('.nav.nav-pills').find('li');
   $(allMenus[0]).find('a').text('Home');
   $(allMenus[1]).find('a').text('Contact me');
   $(allMenus[2]).find('a').text('About Us');
   $(allMenus[3]).find('a').text('Login');
   
 })
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <div class="container">
    <h3>Pills</h3>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the secret!

```css
.notext:before {
  content: "I have a text";
}
```

```html
<div class="notext"></div>
```